# Using Ruby-on-Rails, Sphinx or UltraSphinx and an HTML source (not a database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, ultrasphinx

The documentation states for sphinx-0.9.9-rc2:

The data to be indexed can generally come from very different sources: SQL
databases, plain text files, HTML files, mailboxes, and so on.

However, I can't find any documentation on setting up a a source besides SQL.  The config file doesn't seem to indicate that the source can be anything but a database.  Anyone have any helpful links for setting up sphinx with an HTML source?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [xmlpipe](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#xmlpipe2) (now called xmlpipe2) feature on Sphinx? I've tried it out for XML files and it works just like it does for SQL.

I haven't tried out Sphinx with vanilla HTML files, so I'm guessing you'll need to parse your HTML file and create XML files with the attributes/fields that you want indexed and feed them to Sphinx using xmlpipe.

You can see [here](http://nutrun.com/weblog/distributed-key-value-store-indexing/) and [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=sphinx_xmlpipe2_tutorial) for more.

HTH

Comment: No, I specifically wanted to read in html files, index them and then use that to build a search engine for my site.

I've given up on trying to use Sphinx and have approached the problem from another way.

Here is the most information I was able to find, for anyone else looking:

http://www.sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=3867